# About L5 Autoload How add load all class Written?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The follow is my composer.json

```
  autoload": {
                    "classmap": [
                            "database",
                            "app/library/"
```

if I use folder divide them like follow
[image: if I use folder divide them like follow]

how to add the code could load api & Identity
"app/library/* <---could use like wildcard ?

in Uniqid.php

```
<?php namespace app\library\identity;
```

in rgAPI,php

```
<?php namespace app\library\api;
```

Comment: As long as your `library` is inside the `app` folder. Composer will know how to autoload it using PSR-4. Just make sure to use the right namespaces in your files.

Comment: yes , but it still not work ...namespace like above ,  maybe I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you see class not found then you can try these commands

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

This can make the classes in these folders found again.

Comment: thanks , but it still not work 

occur "App\Http\Controllers\Uniqid' not found"

in Uniqid.php 

<?php namespace app\library\identity;

in rgAPI,php
<?php namespace app\library\api;